# How can I edit the mantissa of a double/float in R?

Tags: r, floating-point, precision

I'm looking for something like `frexp` and `ldexp` from c++, or something else that works directly with the IEEE 754 format.

Comment: This might be a good start: http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gmp/functions/frexpZ

Comment: `library("sos"); findFn("frexp")` also finds `accuracy::frexp` (although you'll have to retrieve it from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/accuracy/ )

Comment: @ben-bolker you can make that an answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `frexpZ` function in the `gmp` package, or the `frexp` function in the `accuracy` package.  The latter package is archived, so you'll have to do something like

```
devtools::install_version("accuracy","1.35")
```

to install it (look in the [package archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/accuracy/) to identify the latest version; you'll also need to have compilation tools installed).

`frexp` says it is just a wrapper around the C math library function.

I found these via `sos::findFn("frexp")`